# GPU stops working after sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, sleep, gpu

This has happened twice in two weeks, and it hadn't happened before. I used to be able to send the PC to sleep mode and nothing would happen. Now, if I do it, when I try to wake it up, the monitor doesn't recieve any signal from the GPU.

To solve this, I have to disconnect the GPU from the motherboard, turn the PC on, turn it off and finally reconnect the GPU for everything to go back to normal.

It's really annoying to open the case and perform those operations every time I want to send the PC to sleep mode. What could be causing this malfunctioning?

**Additional information**

OS: Windows 7

CPU: AMD A10-5800K

GPU: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series

Mother: ASUS A55M-A

Comment: In a nutshell, Windows 7 is NOT recommended for APUs, let alone an APU (AMD A10) plus a discrete graphics card (Radeon R7 200). Use Windows 10 instead *and* install the required AMD drivers.

Comment: @MichaelBay But I've had the same PC for almost 5 years now, and this started happening recently. Something must have changed, right?

Comment: AMD A10-5800K was released late 2012 so it's unlikely you have it for so long but ~4 years old is plausible. Either way, from the start, it was intended to run Windows 8 or newer *and* in UEFI mode, something you might have changed to be able to install Windows 7 from a DVD (requires "Legacy" aka CSM aka "BIOS mode").

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your GPU drivers to newest version? If so, then try to downgrade to older drivers. Generally this is NOT recommended, but sometimes older drivers do work better with older hardware.

Comment: No, I haven't updated anything (at least not deliberately).